# showing error while configuring the secret key in flask

Tags: python

[see in this app.config(SECRET_KEY)='      '] shoing error that is Expression cannot be assignment target[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5lVE.png)

Comment: hey, welcome to the site! this is not the way you ask questions here. please read about how to do that. also, you should review Flask's documentation. people put a lot of work into that. what you're trying to do should be `app.config[SECRET_KEY] = "your value goes here"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be changed to the following:

```py
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "YOUR_KEY_VALUE"
```